# pip stopped working after upgrading anaconda v4.4 to v5.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I ran the command `conda update anaconda` to update anaconda v4.4 to v5.0

After anaconda was successfully upgraded to v5.0, I had problems running `pip`.

This is the error output I see after running `pip`;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.adapters import BaseAdapter, HTTPAdapter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests.adapters'
```

How can I get pip to work again? I am using Windows10, 64-bit python v3.6 anaconda v5.0

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2345

Comment: @Harry, seems like there is no solution from the github thread.

Comment: python -c "import ssl" is it working properly?

Comment: @Harry, I am uninstalling anaconda and doing a fresh re-install. So, I won't be able to test that out anymore.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Had the same problem fixed by renaming the directory:
`%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip`

then running `conda install --force-reinstall pip`

(Then I guess it's safe to remove the renamed directory)

Comment: What do you mean you renamed the directory?

Comment: changed its name, so conda can create a new one.  
just like a backup

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when broken pip. The broken pip caused by the failed upgrade can be fixed by running:

```
!easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.

The problem was fixed by uninstalling anaconda and doing a fresh re-install from the windows installation executable.

Based on this link https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2345, it seems something went wrong with the installation but the problem cannot be reproduced. I do not know what exactly what wrong with `conda update anaconda`.