# Resolving errors in python environment on Windows

Tags: python, msys2

I just started having some problems with python, and would like to fix this the proper way, as a last resort, reinstalling if I have to.

Before Python 3, I had Python 2.7 installed. I then installed Python 3.7 along side it. I don't remember, if the path environment was automatically set, or if i manually set it.
My system variables path contains :

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

So I believe this was set automatically.
My user variables path however contains :

```
C:\Python37\;C:\Python37\Scripts;
```

Would the python installer use the user environment? I'm not sure, so I don't know if I set that myself.

However, the user variables path also contains :

```
%PYTHON_DIR%\Python37\Scripts\;%PYTHON_DIR%\Python37\;%PYTHON_DIR%\Python36\Scripts\;%PYTHON_DIR%\Python36\
```

Again, I don't know if I set this myself, and I have no recollection of setting this in my user variables :

```
PYTHON_DIR = C:\Users\pcuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python
```

...but it's there, and I have two folders in that path.
[image]

I also have this in my user variables path :

```
PYTHON = os.path.expanduser(os.getenv('PYTHON', 'C:\\Python37\\python.exe'))
```

I know I created a python environment. I just have to look for it, as I don't remember where to find it right now.

Here is the problem I am having.
I also am using Python in MSYS, and get this error from Python in C:\msys64\usr\bin :

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000800018040 (most recent call first):
      0 [main] python 1489 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack t
race to python.exe.stackdump
```

I set PYTHONHOME to C:\msys64\usr\bin. That doesn't solve the problem.
I also removed PYTHON_DIR to see if there was a conflict there, but that didn't solve the problem.
Rather, I got another error :

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000800018040 (most recent call first):
      0 [main] python 143 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack tr
ace to python.exe.stackdump
```

So it seems to me my Python environment is messed up, and I want to learn how to set it up correctly, hopefully without having to start over.
How can I get rid of these errors, and get a proper python environment?

Comment: `PYTHON = os.path.expanduser(os.getenv('PYTHON', 'C:\\Python37\\python.exe'))` definitely looks wrong; where exactly do you have this?

Comment: This is in my user variables. I believe it was set by a program, because I know nothing about how to do that.

Comment: You mean in your Windows environment? You can't put Python code there, just static text.

Comment: I'm sure I did not do it, so I figure if a program put it there, it must know what it was doing.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand correctly what you mean by "my user variables".

Comment: I don't find that to be the problem though. I could remove it, and see if it changes anything, but I doubt it will. do you want me to try that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229594/discussion-between-jillinger-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of troubleshooting, I was able to discover where the problem was.
Some files in C:\msys64\usr\lib\python3.8 somehow got deleted, or python 3.8 was installed, but not properly. So I did a reinstall, and python stopped complaining about missing encodings and modules.

Running a test on all python installations

```
MINGW64 ~
# python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 27 2020, 05:27:33)  [GCC 9.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

# python setup_build.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
skipping 'geotools/geotools.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
running install_lib
copying build/lib.mingw-3.8/geotools-cpython-38.dll -> C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geotools-0.1.0-py3.8.egg-info

MINGW32 ~
# python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 27 2020, 06:39:26)  [GCC 9.2.0 32 bit] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

# python setup_build.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
dllwrap: WARNING: dllwrap is deprecated, use gcc -shared or ld -shared instead

skipping 'geotools/geotools.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geotools-0.1.0-py3.8.egg-info
Writing C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geotools-0.1.0-py3.8.egg-info

C:\WINDOWS\system32>py -3.7 -m pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>py -2.7 -m pip list
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please
 upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop s
upport for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pi
p can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#pyt
hon-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ----------
...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\
\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27
', 'C:\\Users\\pcUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages', 'C:\\Py
thon27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pybind11-2.6.2-p
y2.7.egg']
>>> 

C:\WINDOWS\system32>py -3
Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\pcUser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip'
, 'C:\\Users\\pcUser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs', 'C:\\User
s\\pcUser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\pcUser\\App
Data\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37', 'C:\\Users\\pcUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\Py
thon\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\pcUser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Pyth
on\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
>>>

C:\WINDOWS\system32>py -3.6 -m pip list
Package         Version
--------------- --------
...
```

My python environment is good. All working nicely. :)

What I learned...
Using PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH is not neccesary, as was suggested by many... although equally suggessted by many.
From my experience - speaking fron a novice perspective - I would not recommend using them.
Maybe they work for others, but I got errors regardless of how I set it up - whether
C:\Python37 or
C:\Python37\lib or
C:\Users\pcUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 or
C:\msys64\usr\lib\python3.8;C:\msys64\usr\lib\python3.8\site-packages;C:\msys64\usr\lib\python3.8\lib-dynload;C:\msys64\usr\lib\python3.8\distutils

They all return a heap of errors on one installment or other.
So it does not work for me. However, probably works for others.
I am happy though that after probably more than 60 hours, my python environment is back in working order. :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Miniconda is the small version of anaconda which is an excellent environment manager. Miniconda does not include a gui and I feel it is nicer to work with.

To create an environment with

`conda create -n my-test-env python=3.9`

You can activate it using

`conda activate my-test-env`

You can install other packages using

`conda install numpy`.

However, not all python packages are available in conda. You can any pip packages by installing pip

```
conda install pip
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but I already had miniconda installed, and I had created an environment on my external drive, and used pip to install some packages that I could not install on my Python versions on my system. However, I had to uninstall miniconda recently, as it had a problem see this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462998/pip-not-installing-packages/66467535#66467535 
I plan on giving it another try later though. I'll see how things work out here.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PYTHONHOME` to a value like `C:\msys64\usr\bin` is definitely wrong; it should be something like `C:\Python37\Lib` if that's where Python installed its libraries. But try simply unsetting it.

Comment: I already placed it in path, since I prefer that. Is that okay. I think it does the same job.

Comment: Not sure what that means. You added `C:Python37\Lib` to the `PATH`? Probably don't do that, even if somehow is seems to work. The purpose of the `PATH` is to tell Windows where to look for executables.

Comment: Well I didn't actually put C:Python37\Lib in the path. I put the msys one, but however, neither solves the problem. I think I am on the right trail though, and I believe my previous miniconda installation is the culprit. I believe it left some residue in the registry that requires python 3.8 modules. I am sniffing out the problem.

Comment: What I mean by neither worked, is that the C:Python37\Lib in PYTHONHOME does not correct the problem. Also, Correction python 3.9 is what miniconda used, and the module python is looking for is in cpython.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I was sniffing down the wrong trail, but I found something. :D Your directory C:Python37\Lib works, but it doesn't work in PYTHONHOME. It works in PYTHONPATH. So you were on the right track. :) Probably the name difference is a Linux Windows thing, idk. With the Libs in PYTHONPATH the error is gone. Thanks. 
I'll be back with the final verdict. :D

Comment: Could you come up with a cetter title for your question? Currently this looks like "best current practice for a normal Windows installation" rather than "nobody knows what I did and nobody else is ever likely to run into this".

Comment: Huh?
I don't know if your suggestion works on a system you are more familiar with - other than Windows, but the PYTHONHOME isn't working in this situation, and the recommend PYTHONPATH is C:\Python37 , so though the error went away, it created tons of errors, since it's now looking in the Lib folder, when it shouldn't be. So I was wrong. :)
I think I am still on the right track with the python 3.9 module which miniconda used (this from a number of links found while researching the issue). This is about about finding out why there is a problem with my python environment. The title is good. :)

Comment: Really no. If you search for "how to set up Python on Windows" and see this title, would you not think it's relevant? This is a niche special case and should have a correspondingly specific title.

Comment: Sorry. I am not following you. i.e. I don't understand. What do you think the title should be, or what is wrong otherwise, in your opinion?

Comment: Okay. I figured out what you were getting at, and edited the title. Thanks much.

Comment: Changed the title again, but problem solved. Thanks for your patience, and willingness. :)